# In Typescript how do you assure a function parameter is one of a number of defined enums?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

take this enum for example

```
export enum MyEnum {
  a = "a",
  b = "b",
  c = "c"
}
```

and then I define a function type where the parameter has to be one of these

i.e.

`myFunction("c")` is fine

`myFunction("d")` should throw an error

but obviously `const myFunction = (param: string)` would not work here

but also `const myFunction = (param: MyEnum)` does not work

Comment: @jabaa no. it would work with `type X = "A" | "B"` but not enum

Comment: `type fnType = keyof typeof MyEnum`, and then use it

Comment: Note that TS considers string literal values like `"a"` and `"b"` to be incompatible with `enum` values even when those values are `"a"` and `"b"` at runtime.  The point of enums is to be an opaque nominal-ish type.  So what you're asking is not for a function to accept "one of a number of defined enums" but the literal supertypes.  For string enums you could widen to the string literals like `(param: \`${MyEnum}\`) => void` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w65v6W), but this goes against the point of enums; you're not supposed to care about the actual runtime values.

Answer (score 2):

```
const f = (x: MyEnum) => …
```

…will work so long as you call `f` like this:

```js
f(MyEnum.a)
```

It is possible to "import" or alias the enumeration values:

```js
const { a } = MyEnum;
f(a);  // okay
```

```js
const foo = MyEnum.b;
f(foo);  // okay
```

If you wish to use strings, (e.g. `f('a')`) you could use `keyof typeof MyEnum`:

```js
const f = (x: keyof typeof MyEnum) => …
f('a');  // okay
```

…but if this is what you want, you may want to consider defining a union type instead:

```js
type MyEnum = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
const f = (x: MyEnum) => …
f('a');  // okay
```

Comment: You might want to mention that `keyof typeof MyEnum` only works because the keys and values of the enum happen to be identical; a more general enum like `enum Foo { BAR = "baz" }` wouldn't let you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
export enum MyEnum {
  a = "a",
    b = "b",
    c = "c"
}

const myFunction = (param: MyEnum) => {
  console.log(param)
}

myFunction(MyEnum.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
   enum MyEnum {
      a = "a",
      b = "b",
      c = "c"
    }
    
    const myFunction = (param:MyEnum) =>{
        console.log(MyEnum[param]) //or MyEnym.param
    }
    
    myFunction("a") //will log a
    myFunction("d") //will log undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The supported use case for [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) in TypeScript is when you want a set of named constants and you want to refer to them exclusively by *name*.  If you find yourself wanting to deal with the *values* of these enums without the name, then enums are not a great fit.  In the enum

```
enum MyEnum {
  A = "a",
  B = "b",
  C = "c"
}
```

(I changed the keys because they are not in general identical to the values, but what follows is the same no matter what), it is intentionally forbidden for you to assign a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"a"` or `"b"` to a value of the `MyEnum` type:

```
let x: MyEnum;
x = MyEnum.A; // okay
x = "a"; // error! Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'.

const myFunction = (x: MyEnum) => { }
myFunction(MyEnum.A); // okay
myFunction("a"); // error! Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'.
```

Yes, at runtime, `MyEnum.A` and `"a"` are the same value, but the TypeScript compiler takes the position that you should never be referring to the value of an enum except through the enum object itself.

Instead of fighting with or working around this restriction, you can give up on enums and just use a plain object instead:

```
const MyEnum = {
  A: "a",
  B: "b",
  C: "c"
} as const;

type MyEnum = typeof MyEnum[keyof typeof MyEnum];
//type MyEnum = "a" | "b" | "c"

let x: MyEnum;
x = MyEnum.A; // okay
x = "a"; // okay

const myFunction = (x: MyEnum) => { }
myFunction("a"); // okay
myFunction("z"); // error
```

Here we use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to tell the compiler to keep track of the string literal values in the `MyEnum` object.  And now the `MyEnum` object and associated `MyEnum` type don't have any special enum branding to worry about.  The type `MyEnum` is just the union of string literals you care about.  You can write `MyEnum.A` if you want to, but you can also write `"a"`; they are equivalent, both at runtime and in the type system.

---

Still, if you must use an enum, there is a way to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to widen an enum type to corresponding *string* literal values:

```
enum MyEnum {
  A = "a",
  B = "b",
  C = "c"
}

type MyEnumStrings = `${MyEnum}`
// type MyEnumStrings = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

And then you can write your function in terms of that:

```
const myFunction = (x: MyEnumStrings) => { }
myFunction("a"); // okay
myFunction("z"); // error
```

But this doesn't work exactly for numeric enum values:

```
enum Whoops {
  A = "a",
  N = 123
}
type WhoopsStrings = `${Whoops}`
// type WhoopsStrings = "a" | "123"
```

And there won't be a way to do better until and unless something like [microsoft/TypeScript#48094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48094) is merged; this *might* happen for TypeScript 4.7, but I'm not sure.

Personally, I don't think it's worth this kind of hoop-jumping to get an off-label  use of enums working, when you can just use a plain object instead. But that's up to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAhAOwK4FsEFkCeBRNTAb2AQQEEEBeBAIgENaAaUhAIWroCNnWBhTrQDGtYAF9gkgDYhEYAFzZ8hANzAwnXAQwA6cioQB6QwigBrejnWDGB40hgxYAQgQAVHBBAIA5A1o+CACWAM4IyFCI9CEhQQDmyPRcMghwUKme3j5ahD46konoICEQ9ELeACJQyHAA6rBmCCRkQtUhiOg4AGKoyEJwQdWcABQKStroAJTUAHxNCBJknT19A9XDObrkk3Ym5pasy739g8jD-jtGJiCOLuIF9EUlZd7kUnA3iQMAbt7NCK1kO1xoROP8yORFP4WGQyGwoTwYbC+FCRKwxAhogC2nA1GQ4JkQRhOASvFAAGZE9AAbTMIBwFIyZMpm3QAF08VdSd5WTZaAgAD7cflC4SiMgyOSKVmcjQ0Vl6XamCxWMhyui2K7Kg4tHEII6rU4jMas6ZUOZEBaHbrHNZnC5K-aq-U2w3rWgAL1ol3sNycMEkEkk3KpAGU4DAgsg4mEaAADAAkRFZYjjwHsIdZ4cj0djGpFwsFdDRwEBwINJyGNFG0uUGGzUZjZotVordvOjB9exVwDbp3OXq7Dn9khQxNqAAsoFAIGF-pQaNDWAA5TgARgATABme4hyfT2cN3OcRNEfczkKp9MmPdTi9HmN8ou0Tdb2hAA)